# Is almost any group generated by two generators?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, asymptotics, group-presentation, finitely-generated

What is the asymptotic probability that a randomly chosen finite group can be presented with $2$ generators? More precisely, what is $$ \lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{number of 2-generated groups of order} \le n}{ \text{number of groups of order} \le n}$$ if it exists?

Comment: My guess would be that most large $p$-groups will not be 2-generated. However, all finite simple groups are 2-generated (as far as I know, no proof of this is known which does not use the classification).

Comment: (And most groups are large $p$-groups)

Comment: I would reduce to $2-$groups - the vast majority of groups are in this category

Comment: What is the process for "randomly choosing" a finite group?  Also, fun fact: $S_n$ is 2-generated for any $n$.

Comment: 0 is almost certainly the answer. Most finite groups are 2-groups of exponent 4 and nilpotency class 2, but the free 2-group of exponent 4 and nilpotency class 2 generated by 2 elements has order 32.

Comment: A note of caution: all of the statements about most groups being 2-groups or $p$-groups are widely believed to be true, but none of them have been proved, so it seems unlikely that the probability being 0 is provable.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ...non-cyclic...

Comment: @user1729 Indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, almost all groups aren’t. Moreover, a stronger statement is true:

> Suppose $d$ is an arbitrary natural number. Then $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{number of }d \text{-generated groups of order} \le n}{ \text{number of groups of order} \le n} = 0$

To prove this we need two facts.

The first one is the Theorem 1 from “Enumerating Boundedly Generated Finite Groups” by Alexander Lubotzky. It states:

> There exists a constant $c$, such that for any natural $d$ and $n$ the number of $d$-generated groups of order less than $n$ does not exceed $n^{cd\ln(n)}$

The second one is a theorem proved by Charles Sims in “Enumerating $p$-groups”, that states:

> For any prime $p$ and natural $n$ the number of groups of order $p^n$ is $p^{\frac{2}{27}n^3 + O(n^{\frac{8}{3}})}$

Or, to be more exact, its corollary:

> There exists such a constant $b$, that for any natural $n$, the number of groups of order strictly less than $n$ is greater than $n^{b(\ln(n))^2}$

From those statements we get:

$$0 \leq \lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{number of }d \text{-generated groups of order} \le n}{ \text{number of groups of order} \le n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{cd\ln(n)}}{n^{b(\ln(n))^2}} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks! Did I get right that this even implies that for any function $f(n)\in o(ln(n))$ the proportion of groups of order less than n with at most $f(n)$ generators tends to $0$?

Comment: @Domonik, yes, of course.